# How can we use zend_debug to dump values in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I know how to use `var_dump()` to dump values. But I want to know how to use `zend_debug` to output to a log.

Answer (score 0):

just looked at it and it works. 
ive added the false on the 3th param (echo) so that it does not show on the page. You can write the result to a log file. or php log file like below.

```
public function indexAction() {

    $result = Zend_Debug::dump($_REQUEST,'label',false);
    echo 'write this to log ('. $result .')';
    error_log($result);

}
```